# Fixed Header of jsf/tomhawak datatable

Tags: jsf

I'm using richfaces 3.1 and jsf 1.1 and tomhawak , i need to keep fixed header in table.

I have also tried with css , since its working properly in mozila firefox but not in IE.

It would be helpful, if any other approach will be there.

Answer (score 1):

It will be a good idea to post the CSS you tried.

On my application, I have such a header, which is a simple `<div>` (you can use a `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` if you want to stick to JSF components) with specific CSS class:

Here is the default CSS:

```
div.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and for IE6 support, I added:

```
div.fixed-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: expression( ignore = document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since Dynamic properties (also called "CSS expressions") are no longer supported in Internet Explorer 8 and later, in IE8 mode and higher. This decision was made for standards compliance, browser performance, and security reasons. It would be good,if there is any alternative approach or solution. Thanks